# How to connect to an iOS and Android devices remotely for debugging when on different networks

Tags: android, ios, iphone, xcode, ipad

1. I have 2 VMs that are hosted in the AWS cloud.
2. I would like to connect these VMs to my iOS and Android devices that are on my local network so that I can run my Xcode build and Android app.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you considered using https://aws.amazon.com/device-farm/

Comment: I already use it. I want to use some thing free.